Airflow with okta Integration
I followed all the steps mentioned in the document Airflow with Okta integration , But Container is not coming up
Failing user_create function with AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'session' 
Stack Trace
(UTC+5:30)
baseview.datamodel.session = self.session
airflow-worker

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
airflow-worker

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'session'
airflow-worker

File "/home/airflow/.local/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
airflow-worker

sys.exit(main())
airflow-worker

^^^^^^
airflow-worker

File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 62, in main
airflow-worker

args.func(args)
airflow-worker

File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_config.py", line 49, in command
airflow-worker

return func(*args, **kwargs)
airflow-worker

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
airflow-worker

File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 115, in wrapper
airflow-worker

return f(*args, **kwargs)
airflow-worker

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
airflow-worker

File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/utils/providers_configuration_loader.py", line 55, in wrapped_function
airflow-worker

return func(*args, **kwargs)
airflow-worker

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
airflow-worker

File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/providers/fab/auth_manager/cli_commands/user_command.py", line 69, in users_create
airflow-worker

with get_application_builder() as appbuilder:
airflow-worker

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.12/contextlib.py", line 137, in __enter__
airflow-worker

return next(self.gen)
airflow-worker

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
airflow-worker

File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/providers/fab/auth_manager/cli_commands/utils.py", line 52, in get_application_builder
airflow-worker

yield _return_appbuilder(flask_app)
airflow-worker

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
airflow-worker

File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/providers/fab/auth_manager/cli_commands/utils.py", line 39, in _return_appbuilder
airflow-worker

init_appbuilder(app)
airflow-worker

File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/www/extensions/init_appbuilder.py", line 666, in init_appbuilder
airflow-worker

return AirflowAppBuilder(
airflow-worker

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
airflow-worker

File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.12/site-packages/airflow/www/extensions/init_appbuilder.py", line 168, in __init__
airflow-worker

Traceback (most recent call last):```


